# Mercurial subrepo username

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I had to do some work in mercurial repository on another computer. This repository has a subrepo.
The repository remote path is `ssh://remote_username@server/path`, so hg asks me for password for user `remote_username`. However, the subrepository has no username in the remote url, and when pushing, it asks me for password for the local username.
I have not found a way to force it to either authenticate as `remote_username`, or at least prompt for username.
I have tried changing hg config auth section and the subrepo hgrc, but neither worked. I may also update the url in .hgsub to include `remote_username`, but then I would have to push that as well, and everybody would have to authenticate as me, which is not quite desirable.
How can I force hg to use the username I want for remote authentication?

Hg version is 4.2.1.
OS is MacOS.
Protocol is ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution was to create a samba share (this functionality is built into MacOS), mount that from a Windows machine, and then use TortoiseHg's hg client, which prompts for username. This, however, requires another machine with Windows, so it's not much of an answer.

Recently I have found a better solution: create `/Users/local_username/.ssh/config` and add the following to it:

```
Host server
  User remote_username
```

Where `server` is the server's URI and `remote_username` is the username I want to login as.

Worked like a charm.